# Attempted import error: 'Model' is not exported from '../module'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, openapi-generator

Typescript react app inconsistently fails to import an interface definition, even though VS Code resolves the module correctly.

I built a typescript react app with create-react-app and a REST client using openapi code generator based on a swagger specification.

Then, I used the generated interface definitions thorough my application as type definitions.

However, for some reason, I inconsistently can't import one these  definitions from time to time.

I already tried deleting node_modules and `npm install`.

The file that shows the problem (ModelProxy.ts):

```
import { Model } from '../generated'
```

generated module index.ts file:

```
export * from './models'
```

models module index.ts file:

```
export * from './Model'
```

Model.ts file:

```
export interface Model {...
```

Simplified file structure:

```
| src
| - api
| - - proxies
| - - - index.ts
| - - - ModelProxy.ts
| - - generated
| - - - index.ts
| - - - models
| - - - - index.ts
| - - - - Model.ts
```

I import ModelProxy from React components to make api calls and isolate the auto generated code. This pattern have worked just fine for a while now.

What surprised me is that Visual Studio Code resolves the type definitions just fine. The application doesn't build, however.

Build fails with error:

```
./src/api/proxies/ModelProxy.ts
Attempted import error: 'Model' is not exported from '../api'.
```

I changed filenames for confidentiality reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone encountering the same problem, I figured that openapi code generator version 4.0.0 (SNAPSHOT built 01/11/2019) generates typescript code using namespaces to emulate static fields inside interfaces for enums, like this:

```
interface Pet {
  status: Pet.StatusEnum
  ...
}

// later in the file ...

export namespace Pet {
  export enum StatusEnum {
    Available = 'available',
    Pending = 'pending',
    Sold = 'sold'
  }
}
```

[That is not supported by Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8244), what causes the error.

For me, the fix was to manually edit the files to export the enum under a different name, like `PetStatusEnum` in the example and give up namespaces altogether. Like this:

```
interface Pet {
  status: PetStatusEnum
  ...
}

// later in the file ...

export enum PetStatusEnum {
  Available = 'available',
  Pending = 'pending',
  Sold = 'sold'
}
```

OpenAPI maintainers are trying to resolve this in [this issue](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/1947).

Comment: This issue was resolved. Enums are now exported outside the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue on attempt to build some typescript `src` from `node_modules`.

Plugin `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` helped me.